# $2019f'(x)+2020f(x)\geq2021$

Tags: calculus, rolles-theorem

Find all continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which is differentiable on $(0,1)$ and
$$f(0)=f(1)=\frac{2021}{2020}\textrm{ while }2019f'(x)+2020f(x)\geq2021,\forall x\in(0,1).$$

> The Instructor hints me to use Rolle's Theorem, but all I can get is
> $$\exists x_0\in(0,1):f'(x_0)=0\Rightarrow f(x_0)\geq\frac{2021}{2020}.$$
> I guess the only such function is $f\equiv2021/2020.$

Any hints/ideas/comments are appericated. Thank you!

Comment: How did you deduce that $x_0$ was a maximum, and not a minimum? (I assume this is how you got the inequality)

Comment: I see one way: I'll leave it to you to fill the details. Note that, the inequality seems like a first order differential equation with constant coefficients which you can integrate from $0$ to $x$ which allows you to conclude $f(x)$ is always greater than some value (find it) in the given interval. Use that to prove the derivative is always non-negative. Can you finish now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let
$$F(x)=\exp\left(\frac{2020}{2019}x\right)\cdot\left(f(x)-\frac{2021}{2020}\right),\qquad x\in [0,1].$$
Then $F$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$ with
$$F'(x)=\frac1{2019}\exp\left(\frac{2020}{2019}x\right)\cdot\left(2020f(x)-2021+2019f'(x)\right)\geq 0.$$
Hence $F$ is nondecreasing. Also we have $F(0)=F(1)=0$, so $F(x)=0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Therefore,
$$f(x)=\frac{2021}{2020},\qquad\forall x\in[0,1].$$

*Remark*. If $F$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$ with $F(0)=F(1)$ and $F'(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in (0,1)$, then $F$ is constant on $[0,1]$. This is a consequence of the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), which can be proved using Rolle's theorem, see [the proof on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Proof).